# Looking for alternative of javscript eval function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using the following function to make an XHR request and execute javascript from the response if possible:

```js
function ajaxRequest(resultDiv, processing, action, paramName, param, paramName2, param2, parseJs) {
  if (processing) {
    document.getElementById(resultDiv).innerHTML = processing;
  }
  var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      var resp = this.responseText;
      document.getElementById(resultDiv).innerHTML = resp;
      if (parseJs) {
        parseScript(resp);
      }
    }
  }
  if (paramName2) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/query?" + paramName + "=" + param + "&" + paramName2 + "=" + param2 + "&action=" + action, true);
  } else {
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/query?" + paramName + "=" + param + "&action=" + action, true);
  }
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function parseScript(strcode) {
  var scripts = new Array();
  while (strcode.indexOf("<script") > -1 || strcode.indexOf("</script") > -1) {
    var s = strcode.indexOf("<script");
    var s_e = strcode.indexOf(">", s);
    var e = strcode.indexOf("</script", s);
    var e_e = strcode.indexOf(">", e);
    scripts.push(strcode.substring(s_e + 1, e));
    strcode = strcode.substring(0, s) + strcode.substring(e_e + 1);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    try {
      eval(scripts[i]);
    } catch (ex) {
      alert("Error while executing");
    }
  }
}
```

But I got to know that eval function is somehow dangerous and very slow. So can you help me to find something alternative of eval and rewrite the code snippet to work same way it meant to be but with alternative of eval? Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: there really is not an alternative

Comment: @epascarello so do you know how other sites achieve this functionality? do they use eval too?

Comment: You're evaluating arbitrary JavaScript. That's the exact usecase for `eval`. I'd question though whether you should be doing this in the first place. You want to evaluate all JavaScript in a response? Why do you need this functionality?

Comment: Most sites do not return scripts that need to be evaluated.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, for example, to showing toasts or modal. (note: I use materializecss framework).

Comment: Just load the script as text, create a new `<script>` element, set the content of the script to the text, and insert the new element into the DOM. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/1762224

Comment: In the case where you're trying to show toasts or modals, I think most people would generally return the *content* of the modal and handle the showing/hiding in the front end

Comment: I think I found a solution. using @GirkovArpa's code I altered the function. Now the function doesn't executes with eval function. also the code comes from response is only gets executed. so I think there is no way to inject any code in ajax response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to `eval()` might be to inject the code into a `<script>` tag on your page, upon which it is then immediately executed.

In the example below, the code is provided to `script.text`.  For a URL as in your question, use `script.src` instead.

```js
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.text = 'console.log("foo");';
document.body.append(script);
// logs "foo"
```

Comment: is there any vulnerabilities like eval?

Answer (score -1):

Eval can be slow but is as dangerous as any other solution if you are running code that is not trusted or verified by yourself. If you do need another way to run this you can try dynamic script text insertion as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605073/alternatives-to-eval-for-running-remote-code)

Comment: so is it possible to meddle in the eval function and do something bad (attack) b users or hackers?

Comment: @Meraj-UlIslam That depends on where the imported JS comes from. If it's at all user supplied, the JS may contain code that steals session cookies or something, and eval'ing that would be bad.

Comment: _"That depends on where the imported JS comes from"_ - Why imported JS? You just have to call `parseScript()` with your "evil" payload. And this can be quite easy (depending on other problems of the site).

Comment: it's like: a user typed a comment on post. then the comment posted via ajax. in ajax hosted file (php) tries to save the comment. and then the result shown immediately via some js execution (modal for example). and reloads the comments dynamically. nothing that executes comes from user. but I wonder if user can take advantage of eval function in any way.